# Spark Machine Learning - Error Number Format Exception when Count Rating

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, bigdata

i have rating data stored in **HBase**, that has format `(user,item,activity)`. using Scala and Spark, i try to count rating but failed because Error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "320629062016"
```

Below are my code :

```
  val HBaseRDD = sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConfiguration, classOf[TableInputFormat],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])


    val raw_hbaserdd = HBaseRDD.map{
      kv => kv._2
    }.filter( x => x != null)


    /* Transform HBASE-RDD to WEIGHT-RDD */
    val raw_ArticleWeightRDD = raw_hbaserdd.map {
      result =>  val r = scala.util.Random
        val rs1  = r.nextInt(1000000000).toString()
        val rs2 = r.nextInt(1000000000).toString()
        val rs = rs1+rs2
        val x = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("data"),Bytes.toBytes("user")))
        val y = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("data"),Bytes.toBytes("item")))
        val z = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("data"),Bytes.toBytes("activity")))
        (rs, (x,y,z))
    }

    val filter_ArticleWeightRDD = raw_ArticleWeightRDD.filter ( x => x._2._1 != null).filter(x => x._2._1 != "ï»¿1")
    val _ArticleWeightRDD = filter_ArticleWeightRDD.map {
      result => (result._1, (result._2._1.toInt, result._2._2.toInt, result._2._3.toInt))
    }


    val ArticleWeightRDD = _ArticleWeightRDD.map {
      result => result._2._3 match {
        case 10 => (result._1.toLong,  Rating(result._2._1.toInt, result._2._2.toInt, CONSTANT_READ_WEIGHT.toDouble ))
        case 8  => (result._1.toLong,  Rating(result._2._1.toInt, result._2._2.toInt, CONSTANT_PLAY_WEIGHT.toDouble ))
        case 3  => (result._1.toLong,  Rating(result._2._1.toInt, result._2._2.toInt, CONSTANT_SHARE_WEIGHT.toDouble ))
      }
    }
    val numRatings = ArticleWeightRDD.count
```

I got error in last line (`val numRatings = ArticleWeightRDD.count`)

Any Idea ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your number - `320629062016` is too large to be an `Int`. Max possible value of an `Int` is - `2147483647`. If you are trying to use it as an `Int` anywhere in your code, it will cause you problems. Try reading it as `Long` which supports a max value upto - `9223372036854775807`

Comment: @so what'is the solution? Rating Constructor in Spark only requred (Int,Int,Double) where first param is integer. How about if my client's user need very long length of integer ?

Comment: First try ensuring that your `_ArticleWeightRDD` computes fine, if you read the values as `Long` instead of `Int`. Then you can think about Rating problem later.